# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound --- Couldn't find User without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to make a simple button to redirect the user to their own user page.

Here is the button on the application.html

```
<li><%= link_to "My Profile", {:controller => "users", :action => "show", :id => session[:user_id] }, :method => "get" %></li>
```

Controller with my show method left blank

```
def show
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here is the route

```
match '/myprofile', to: 'users#show', via: 'get'
```

I feel like I am missing something very simple, regardless, any help is much appreciated. Thanks

When I click the My Profile button, the @user = User.find(params[:id]) is highlighted.

Comment: Can you just write `user_path(session[:user_id])` instead of `:controller => "users", :action => "show", :id => session[:user_id] }, :method => "get"`?

Comment: I just tried that but still got the same error.

Comment: I just created a new user and the button worked this time. I think I may have been trying to access a user that had old information that no longer works with my new code. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What does your log say? It will show (a) which action is getting called and (b) the parameters being sent in.

Could be as simple as `params[:id]` being either the wrong `id`, or`nil` for some reason.